# Run application without install permissions

Tags: flash, activex

I'm trying to build an app, which should have Flash Player control, which plays SWF from server (certain URL). For Flash Player ActiveX you have to save SWF file to a temporary location to load it and play, isn't it?

You'll have to create a corresponding link that you can pass to the Flash Player ActiveX and then delete SWF file after it is played. Of course, high security level can't be guaranteed, but I think it's good, if at least no temporary files are created (can be intercepted LOCALLY). So the question is how to make Flash Player ActiveX be able to load SWF file directly from any source without usage of temp files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use f-in-box. It extends features Flash. You can download it from f-in-box.com